# General IoC practice - is it wrong for services to depend on each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Right now I have a few services that are defined in an assembly that is not dependent on an IoC container (Ninject in my case). In the main project I have an IRepository for data access registered in the container.

```
this.Bind<IRepository>().To<EntityFrameworkRepository<MyDatabaseEntities>>();
```

I also have IAuthenticationService and IErrorLogger services registered, whose concrete implementation I want to use the repository for their logic. However, I am not sure how to best accomplish this. Currently, my constructor on both concrete implementations take an IRepository parameter and I pass it in when I register them:

```
this.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<MyAuthenticationService>().
                WithConstructorArgument("myRepository", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IRepository());
```

Here I just tell the container to grab the IRepository instance and pass it to the constructor.

I didn't feel right about making my service assembly depend on ninject or even the common service locator (CSL), but I am not sure about my current way either. I am looking for opinions and alternate solutions.

If my other services don't use an IRepository, I would have to create new concrete implementations of these services for each type of underlying IRepository type (e.g. an AuthenticationService for both fake and real data). It would be a lot of logic repetition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your service assembly should not depend on Ninject, only on the interfaces that you register your concrete types for. The IoC container should be only the aggregate root to inject dependencies into your classes. The assembly that contains the aggregate root / the Ninject kernel on the other hand will depend on all of the assemblies that contain the concrete types (how else would it be able to resolve them?).

In general with IoC you should apply the [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle_%28computer_programming%29) here - you should *give* the dependencies to your concrete object instances (using constructor injection if at all possible), not let the object instances *ask* for their dependencies.

The example you use for `WithConstructorArgument()` should not be needed at all actually, since dependency resolution works recursively: You have registered both `IRepository` and `IAuthenticationService` with the container, so it knows how to resolve both. Because `IAuthenticationService` is bound to `AuthenticationService`you do not need to specify the constructor argument since it is of type `IRepository` and will be resolved automatically.

As to the repetition - of course you will have to create *different implementations* for `IRepository` for different repository types assuming you want *different behavior* of these repositories.

Comment: Great information! You are correct, I did not need to specify the WithConstructorArgument at all. They were automatically injected. One other question is what if I register 2 IRepository implementations, each with a different name. Then I want to specify the one to inject. I know there is a NamedAttribute with Ninject, but to avoid adding a Ninject dependency to my service assembly I wouldn't want to use that. So manually specifying would be the way to go in this case? FYI, my repetition concern was not about IRepository but the other service classes.

Comment: For Ninject you could use `WhenInjectedInto<Foo>()` where Foo is your service class. Typically you would only register one concrete implementation of your repository - the ones for fake data and testing should not be registered as part of your main application, only in a separate test container